# single line reduce statement not working - how to fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, reduce

when i try to use commented code (multi line reduce statement) its working fine.
however when i try to use single line reduce statement, its not working.
i understand its due to splice command in the reduce statement.
can anyone advise how to overcome this type of scenario to write reduce statement in single line?

```
function order(words){
    // ...
    let regex = /\d+/g;
    let matches = words.match(regex)

    // return words.split(' ').reduce((finalar, element, indx) => {
    //     console.log('matches', matches);
    //     finalar.splice(matches[indx] - 1, 0, element)
    //     console.log('element', element);
    //     return finalar;
    // }, []).join(' ');
    return words.split(' ').reduce((finalar, element, indx) => finalar.splice([matches[indx] - 1],0,element) , []);
}

console.log(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"));  //Output: Thi1s is2 3a T4est
```

Comment: `splice` returns the deleted items. do you need to use `reduce`? why not map a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the splitted string with the values of matches as indices.

```js
function order(words) {
    const
        regex = /\d+/g,
        matches = words.match(regex);

    return words
        .split(' ')
        .map((_, i, a) => a[matches[i] - 1])
        .join(' ');
}

console.log(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a")); //Output: Thi1s is2 3a T4est
```